Tidyverse/Dplyr solution to assigning values to column names extracted from a nested list
I have a tibble with a column containing a nested list (<list<list<double>>> data type to be specific).
It looks something like the following (but in R/Arrow format):



ID
nestedvals




001
[[1]] (1,0.1) [[2]] (2,0.2) [[3]] (3,0.3) [[4]] (4,0.4) [[5]] (5,0.5)


002
[[1]] (1,0.1) [[2]] (2,0.2) [[3]] (3,0.3) [[4]] (4,0.4)


003
[[1]] (1,0.1) [[2]] (2,0.2) [[3]] (3,0.3)


004
[[1]] (1,0.1) [[2]] (2,0.2)


005
[[1]] (1,0.1)



Where if I call row 1 of nestedvals I get:
tibble$nestedvals[1]
<list<list<double>>[1]>
[[1]]
<list<double>[5]>
[[1]]
[1] 1   0.1

[[2]]
[1] 2   0.2

[[3]]
[1] 3   0.3

[[4]]
[1] 4   0.4

[[5]]
[1] 5   0.5

Basically, for the nestedvals column, there is a list containing a list of pairs of doubles, with the first indicating a specific index (e.g. 5), and a certain value (e.g. 0.5).
What I would like to do is generate set of zero-filled columns based on the range of unique indexes of each nested list. e.g.:
col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5
And then replace each 0 with the value (second number in the nested list), based on the index (first number in each nested list), for each row of the tibble.
I believed the best way to do this involves unlisting the variables and making separate columns with the lists of indexes and lists of values of interest, both so I can find the maximum for name generation in the former and for assignment between to two.
To accomplish this, I wrote a function to split each nested list:
  nestsplit <- function(x, y) {
    unlist(lapply(x, `[[`, y))
  }

And then generate unique columns with the column names (by index) and values of interest to append to the tibble:
  tibble <-
    tibble |> rowwise() |> mutate(index_names = list(paste0(
      "col_", as.character(nestsplit(nestedvals, 1))
    )),
    index_values = list(nestsplit(nestedvals, 2)))

But I would like to see if there is an efficient, row-wise, tidyverse/dplyr-based solution to assign the values in index_values to index-based column names using the information in the index_names variable, rather than writing a loop to assign each of them by row.
So that an output like this:



ID
nestedvals
col_1
col_2
col_3
col_4
col_5




001
<Nested list of 5 pairs of values>
0
0
0
0
0


002
<Nested list of 4 pairs of values>
0
0
0
0
0


003
<Nested list of 3 pairs of values>
0
0
0
0
0


004
<Nested list of 2 pairs of values>
0
0
0
0
0


005
<Nested list of 1 pair of values>
0
0
0
0
0



Instead looks like the following:



ID
nestedvals
col_1
col_2
col_3
col_4
col_5




001
<Nested list of 5 pairs of values>
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5


002
<Nested list of 4 pairs of values>
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0


003
<Nested list of 3 pairs of values>
0.1
0.2
0.3
0
0


004
<Nested list of 2 pairs of values>
0.1
0.2
0
0
0


005
<Nested list of 1 pair of values>
0.1
0
0
0
0



To generate some example data for above, please use:
tibble <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005),
      nestedvals = structure(
        list(
          structure(
            list(c(1, 0.1), c(2, 0.2), c(3, 0.3), c(4, 0.4), c(5, 0.5)),
            class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
            ptype = numeric(0)
          ),
          structure(
            list(c(1, 0.1), c(2, 0.2), c(3, 0.3), c(4, 0.4)),
            class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
            ptype = numeric(0)
          ),
          structure(
            list(c(1, 0.1), c(2, 0.2), c(3, 0.3)),
            class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
            ptype = numeric(0)
          ),
          structure(
            list(c(1, 0.1), c(2, 0.2)),
            class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
            ptype = numeric(0)
          ),
          structure(
            list(c(1, 0.1)),
            class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
            ptype = numeric(0)
          )
        ),
        ptype = structure(
          list(),
          class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"),
          ptype = numeric(0)
        ),
        class = c("arrow_list", "vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -5L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )


tibble%>%
   unnest_longer(nestedvals) %>%
   unnest_wider(nestedvals, names_sep = '_') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = nestedvals_1, names_prefix = 'col_',
               values_from = nestedvals_2, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5
2     2   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0  
3     3   0.1   0.2   0.3   0     0  
4     4   0.1   0.2   0     0     0  
5     5   0.1   0     0     0     0  


Note that in the case the elements are indexed 1:n,like in your example just use unnest_wider:
unnest_wider(tibble, nestedvals, names_sep = '_', transform = ~.x[2])

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID nestedvals_1 nestedvals_2 nestedvals_3 nestedvals_4 nestedvals_5
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1          0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4          0.5
2     2          0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4         NA  
3     3          0.1          0.2          0.3         NA           NA  
4     4          0.1          0.2         NA           NA           NA  
5     5          0.1         NA           NA           NA           NA  

You can easily replace the NA with 0:
tibble %>%
  unnest_wider(nestedvals, names_sep = '_', transform = ~.x[2]) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('nestedvals'), ~replace_na(., 0)))

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID nestedvals_1 nestedvals_2 nestedvals_3 nestedvals_4 nestedvals_5
  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1          0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4          0.5
2     2          0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4          0  
3     3          0.1          0.2          0.3          0            0  
4     4          0.1          0.2          0            0            0  
5     5          0.1          0            0            0            0  


Just to add to the discussion, I attempted the first code block and it threw an error:
  #Error in `pivot_wider()`:   #! Can't convert `fill` <double> to <list>.   #Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Trying the third block now but it's taking a minute on the real data.

@TDeramus there is no fill in the data provided. I do not know where you are getting fill from

I'm not sure myself.
values_fill is the closest thing to that I could have called.
Checking for typos.

Not a typo I'm afraid.
Looks like an error within pivot_wider() itself.
`Backtrace:
▆

├─tidyr::pivot_wider(...)
└─tidyr:::pivot_wider.data.frame(...)`


@TDeramus am sorry I am unable to follow. Are you saying the code I provided has an error in this example? probably consider restarting your Rkernel and running this code again. There should be no fill anywhere. Unless you have different data than the one provided

It's not the same unfortunately.
Have to provide a toy example because I can't share the real thing.
I don't think it's an error in your code, I think it just may not be translating from the toy to the real well.

The one in the third code block is actually running, it's just taking an exceptionally long time because the non-toy data is ~220k rows with those index values ranging from 1-1500.

It definitely works.
Will just have to divide it into a series of smaller scripts to generate the output in a timely fashion.
Thanks so much!

@TDeramus did the code take 7hours!!! Use data.table. That would cut down the time.

How so if I may ask?

You can bind the nested values into data frames, unnest, then pivot:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dat |>
  mutate(cols =  map(nestedvals, ~ setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, .x), c("col", "val")))) |>
  unnest(cols) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = val, values_fill = 0, names_prefix = "col_")

# A tibble: 5 × 7
     ID nestedvals col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
  <dbl> <arrw_lst> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1        [5]   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5
2     2        [4]   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0  
3     3        [3]   0.1   0.2   0.3   0     0  
4     4        [2]   0.1   0.2   0     0     0  
5     5        [1]   0.1   0     0     0     0  


just noticed no much difference between my code and your code.

Yours is better - not sure why I didn't think to just unnest it that way.

This one threw a similar error to @Onyambu's:
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: cols = map(...).
Caused by error in map():
ℹ In index: 55398.
Caused by error in names(object) <- nm:
! 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: cols = map(...).
Caused by error in map():
ℹ In index: 55398.
Caused by error in names(object) <- nm:
! 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]


Might be the problem of having to use toy data (HIPAA reasons) rather than the real thing, as the size of the arrow list can vary a lot.

Did you inspect the data at the index in the error (55398)?  Hard to troubleshoot when we don't have your data.

This would be why:
<list<list<double>>[1]>
[[1]]
<list<double>[0]>
Some of them come up empty it seems.
Will need to filter those out first.

WIth the blanks removed, this is now throwing an error of:
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: cols = map(...).
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in do.call():
! second argument must be a list
